# Syntax for "doesn't do this thing" but "will"

Tags: punctuation, commas

Working on this sentence:

> I look forward to iOS in the Car so the one clock that doesn't set itself automatically will.

Recognizing that it (intentionally) feels non-standard, is it grammatically correct? Or should there be a comma before "will"?

Comment: What, exactly, is your concern? (And why _Car_ with an initial capital?)

Comment: I wasn't sure if there might need to be a comma before "will" or if it was just incorrect in general. It sounds right to me, but putting it to paper made me second guess myself. ("Car" is capitalized because the name of the product is "iOS in the Car".)

Comment: Then you need to ask yourself whether a comma would help the reader in any way. I can't see that it would. _That doesn't set itself automatically_ is a defining relative clause, and defining relative clauses are not set off by commas.

Comment: Alan, if you consider that the answer given accurately answers your question, you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no need for a comma in this sentence:

> I look forward to [product] so the one clock that doesn't set itself automatically will.

The extended form of the sentence is:

> I look forward to [product] so the one clock that doesn't set itself automatically will now set itself automatically.